# Mac-like keyboard layout switching in Fedora 16

Tags: fedora, gnome3

I have a Mac in the office and PC in home.

Is there a way to tweak Fedora 16 with Gnome3 to use Mac-like keyboard switch shortcur? (Left win + Space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest preconfigured one in Gnome 3 is Alt+Space.

Go to **System Settings** > **Keyboard Layout** > **Layouts** > **Options ...**.

Expand the **Key(s) to change layout** menu and click the checkbox on the shortcut sequence you like the best.

Comment: And can I change some configuration manually or add some custom hotkey?

Comment: Sadly, there isn't an easy way to add a custom key sequence to Gnome 3 for changing the keyboard layout. You could write your own shell script that interfaces with 'setxkbmap' to change the keyboard layout, though this would take a lot more effort.

Comment: Ok, can you provide some links to read about it?

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172068/slow-keyboard-layout-switching-in-gnome-3-6 ... the point is that for switching keyboard layout just with modifiers you need to use gnome-tweak-tool.